# BIRT: Java - eventhandler, loaction of the files

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting, birt

I want to implement eventhandling for my reports via java-classes... where do i have to put the files? And do i need .class-files or .jar-files?

BIRT 2.1.3, RCP - Designer

Answer (score 0):

It was covered in [BIRT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/JavaEventHandlers).